# classList.add() is not activated immediately in clicked event

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
function highlight1(){
  document.getElementById("div1").classList.add("red");
}
function highlight2(){
  document.getElementById("div2").classList.add("red");
}
function highlight3(){
  document.getElementById("div3").classList.add("red");
}
```

```css
div{
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;   
}
div:hover{
  background: yellow;
}
.red{
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" onclick="highlight1()">Division</div>
<div id="div2" onclick="highlight2()">Division</div>
<div id="div3" onclick="highlight3()">Division</div>
```

I'm new to CSS and I have two questions for the code.

- (1) When I click the divs, they are not turning red until I move the
  pointer outside of the divs? What is the reason? How can I make it
  highlighted immediately?
- (2) How can I just highlight the div of
  three that I clicked? I only want to highlight one div at the same
  time.

Comment: Probably because when you're over the `div`, the `div:hover` is still being applied, so you only see the red once you move off of the `div` and the `hover` `background` disappears.

Comment: @EvanKnowles even if you change `div:hover` to `.d:hover` and add `class='d'` to the divs and `.red` to `.red:hover`, the `classList` or css is not applied until after the `div` is interacted with via a click. whyyyy? i never remember this being a problem back in the day. just a chrome problem, possibly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `:hover` is making hovered `div`s, even `.red` `div`s, appear hovered (yellow) instead of red. You could make hovered `.red` divs red as well if you wanted.

If you only want one to be red at a time, you can remove `.red` from all divs before using `classList.add`.

It would also be more appropriate to use classes than individual `id`s, because the elements are *part of a collection* rather than being unique in some way:

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
function reset(i) {
  divs.forEach(div => div.classList.remove("red"));
  divs[i].classList.add('red');
}
```

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.box:hover {
  background: yellow;
}

.red,
.red:hover {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" onclick="reset(0)">Division</div>
<div class="box" onclick="reset(1)">Division</div>
<div class="box" onclick="reset(2)">Division</div>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by applying, `div.red:hover` by doing this you are actually overriding `div:hover` with `div.red:hover` prioritizing `div.red:hover`

```js
function highlight1(){
  document.getElementById("div1").classList.add("red");
}
function highlight2(){
  document.getElementById("div2").classList.add("red");
}
function highlight3(){
  document.getElementById("div3").classList.add("red");
}
```

```css
div{
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;   
}
div:hover{
  background: yellow;
}
div.red:hover,.red{
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" onclick="highlight1()">Division</div>
<div id="div2" onclick="highlight2()">Division</div>
<div id="div3" onclick="highlight3()">Division</div>
```